# Redirecting a Wordpress Form Submission to a New Page

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, forms

I currently have a form that is created using wordpress:

```
[contact-form][contact-field label='What do you want him to say?' type='textarea' required='1'/]Word Limit: 50 words[contact-field label='Email' type='text' required='1'/][/contact-form]
```

I want people to click the submit button (I would actually like to change this button to "continue") and have people redirected to a new page.

Does anyone know how to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never used WordPress, but after doing a little bit of research, it seems like you're using a plugin called "Contact Form 7." You should try reading their documentation on redirecting to a different page after submission:

> The simplest way is utilizing Contact Form 7’s custom DOM event to run JavaScript. The following is an example of script that redirects you to another URL when the wpcf7mailsent event occurs:
>
> ```
> <script>
> document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
>     location = 'http://example.com/';
> }, false );
> </script>
> ```

https://contactform7.com/redirecting-to-another-url-after-submissions/